# ASP .Net Core Identity Role Claims not adding to User

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I'm having issues with using Role/Claims.

I have created Roles and given the roles claims. Then assigned these roles to the users, from what I read online this means the User should inherit the Role Claims but they don't. The policy's didn't work and upon further inspection I couldn't see the claims when outputting the user claims via JSON.

All the data is being saved in the database as I can see it.

Role/Claim Seeder

```
 public static void SeedRolesAndClaims(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        // Create Roles
        IdentityRole adminRole = new IdentityRole("Admin");
        roleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole).Wait();

        roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "edit.post")).Wait();
        roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "delete.post")).Wait();
        roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "create.post")).Wait();
        roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "view.post")).Wait();
        roleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "create.comment")).Wait();

        IdentityRole userRole = new IdentityRole("User");
        roleManager.CreateAsync(userRole).Wait();
        roleManager.AddClaimAsync(userRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "create.comment")).Wait();

    }
```

User Seeder

```
ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "john@email.com", FirstName = "Admin", LastName = "Smith", Email = "john@email.com" };
        userManager.CreateAsync(user, "Password123*").Wait();
        userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin").Wait();
```

The check i'm doing is

```
        var claims = User.Claims.Select(claim => new { claim.Type, claim.Value }).ToArray();
        return Json(claims);
```

Which returns the basic JSON claims for authentication

```
[{"type":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier","value":"05bef53e-dd97-41f6-beee-531501cf8598"},{"type":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name","value":"john@email.com"},{"type":"AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp","value":"SGS23ZGIY6UYOOL2APWRIZKNT2V6QBJC"}]
```

I'm not sure what the issue is and have been searching on google/stackoverflow for a while to no prevail.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 6):

If you are using .Net Core 2.1 , it seems you will need to change the default Identity configuration according to [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813) .

In .Net Core 2.1 ,  you could firstly create your own `ApplicationUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

Modify your dbcontext :

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
}
```

Configure the identity using the old-style api :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(
        Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
.AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
.AddDefaultUI()
.AddDefaultTokenProviders()
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

And seed the user and role like :

```
private async Task CreateUserRoles(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    var RoleManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
    var UserManager = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();

    IdentityResult roleResult;
    //Adding Admin Role
    var roleCheck = await RoleManager.RoleExistsAsync("Admin");
    if (!roleCheck)
    {

        IdentityRole adminRole = new IdentityRole("Admin");
        //create the roles and seed them to the database
        roleResult = await RoleManager.CreateAsync(adminRole);

        RoleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "edit.post")).Wait();
        RoleManager.AddClaimAsync(adminRole, new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthorizationDecision, "delete.post")).Wait();

        ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = "v-nany@hotmail.com", Email = "v-nany@hotmail.com" };
        UserManager.CreateAsync(user, "xxxxxx").Wait();

        await UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Admin");
    }

}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env ,IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseCookiePolicy();

    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });

    CreateUserRoles(serviceProvider).Wait();
}
```

At last ,logout and re-signin the account , the claim should be there :

[image]

If you are using .Net Core 2.0 , your code should work with the default identity template .

Comment: This is an intersting approach. Don't know if this is different in CORE 3.1 which I am using, but a lot more things need to be registered in order for RoleManager and UserManager to resolve. Initially it's not completely clear to be what all the concrete implementations passed into these constructors should be.