# Role Claim won't be added when adding Role to User [JwtAuthentication]

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, authorization, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to add role-based authorization to my aspnetcore backend.
For example I want a "Moderator" role that has access to different endpoints.
For this i tried to use a bit of this tutorial : [AspnetCore Identity Roles](https://www.yogihosting.com/aspnet-core-identity-roles/).
The problem I have now is that when I add the a User to a role and use the `[Authorize(Role="Moderator]` attribute it wont work and I always get a 403.

Example Test Case:

```cs
[Fact]
public async Task It_should_return_404_for_non_existing_movies()
{
    using var scope = _factory.Services.CreateScope();
    var userManager = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
    var arrangeContext = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MovieDBContext>();

    await userManager.CreateAsync(
    new IdentityUser { UserName = "Mod", Email = "mod@testuser.com" }, "mod12345");

    var mod = await userManager.FindByNameAsync("Mod");
    await userManager.AddToRoleAsync(mod!, "Moderator");

    var token = await _client.LoginAsync("mod@testuser.com", "mod12345");

    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    var response = await _client.DeleteAsync($"/movies/1337");
    response.StatusCode.Should().Be(HttpStatusCode.NotFound); // This fails because User.Claims does not contain role moderator
}
```

Endpoint im calling in the test (Still WIP):

```cs
[HttpDelete("{id}"), Authorize(Roles = "Moderator")]
public IActionResult DeleteMovie(int id)
{
    var movie = _context.Movies.Find(id);
    if (movie == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    _context.Movies.Remove(movie);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return Ok();
}
```

Startup.cs where I add the aspnetcore identity and auth stuff:

```cs
services
    .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddJwtBearer(config =>
    {
        config.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero,
            ValidateIssuer = true,
            ValidateAudience = true,
            ValidateLifetime = true,
            ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
            ValidIssuer = Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Issuer"),
            ValidAudience = Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Audience"),
            IssuerSigningKey =
                new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration.GetValue<string>("JwtSettings:Key")!)),
        };
    });

services.AddAuthorization();


services
    .AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>(options =>
    {
        options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false;
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
     })
     .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
     .AddEntityFrameworkStores<UserContext>();
```

UserContext.cs:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace MovieDatabase.Identity;
public class UserContext : IdentityDbContext<IdentityUser, IdentityRole, string>
{
    public UserContext(DbContextOptions<UserContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
            .HasData(
                new[] {
                    new IdentityRole { Name = "Admin", NormalizedName = "ADMIN" },
                    new IdentityRole { Name = "Moderator", NormalizedName = "MODERATOR" },
                    new IdentityRole { Name = "User", NormalizedName = "USER" } }
            );

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Here i am also adding the roles that i want to support for now using a migration.
If im checking the claims of a user that is created like im doing in my test this is the result:

```json
[
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
    "value": "TokenForTheApiWithAuth"
  },
  {
    "type": "jti",
    "value": "2b9fb336-50b2-4569-845d-6c596eed39a2"
  },
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
    "value": "080291d2-03b3-40dd-ac39-1793ba7e7b0d"
  },
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name",
    "value": "test"
  },
  {
    "type": "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress",
    "value": "test@example.com"
  },
  {
    "type": "exp",
    "value": "1697668413"
  },
  {
    "type": "iss",
    "value": "http://localhost:5278"
  },
  {
    "type": "aud",
    "value": "http://localhost:5253"
  }
]
```

AspNetUser Table:
[image]

AspNetRoles Table:
[image]

AspNetUserRoles Table:

[image]

As seen above my user is connected in to the role in the database and if i use the UserManager to ask if the User got the "Moderator" role it will return true, but the Role Claim is still missing (s. JSON above).
Im kind of stuck on this problem for a few days now maybe some sees what im missing.

I tried lots of different things for example:
Most of the Solutions found here [Github Issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1813)
after i found this stack overflow question: [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54064048/asp-net-core-identity-role-claims-not-adding-to-user).

Also tried the solution in this question like adding `.AddRoleManager(RoleManager<IdentityRole)` in the `statup.cs` or adding `services.AddScoped<IUserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser>, UserClaimsPrincipalFactory<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>>();`

But nothing seems to add the Role Claim to the User when adding the user to the role.

Github Repo with all the code: https://github.com/alexanderluettig/movie-database/tree/main

Comment: Hi @Alexander Luettig, what is your `LoginAsync` method? Have your add the role claims like:`new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "YourRoleNameHere"),`?

Comment: Hi,
My `LoginAsync` is an [exntension Method](https://github.com/alexanderluettig/movie-database/blob/main/MovieDatabase.Backend.Tests/HttpClientAuthExtension.cs) i wrote for the HTTP Client which calls my [login endpoint](https://github.com/alexanderluettig/movie-database/blob/main/MovieDatabase.Backend/Controllers/Authentication/AuthenticationController.cs). But wouldnt adding the claim by hand defeat the purpose of using the roles in the first place ? I would expect that that if i use the userManager to add the roles i would automatically add the claim

Comment: Hi @Alexander Luettig, due to you use the jwt authentication, you must add the role claims manually. Only if you use the default cookie authentication, you just need use SignInManager to login and it will pass the authorization by role.

Comment: Ahh i see. Yeah i got it to work by adding the role claims when creating my token inside my [Tokenservice.cs](https://github.com/alexanderluettig/movie-database/blob/main/MovieDatabase.Backend/Services/TokenService.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after the comment from @Rena that when using `JwtAuthentication` that the Role Claims won't be added automatically, when creating the jwt Token. I added them manually when creating the Jwt Token inside my [Tokenservice.cs](https://github.com/alexanderluettig/movie-database/blob/main/MovieDatabase.Backend/Services/TokenService.cs)

The lines i added were:

```cs
var roles = _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user).Result;
claims.AddRange(roles.Select(role => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role)));
```